# 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, django, django-models, notifications

i am trying to create a notifications system but am facing issues doing so.

here is my code:

I created a Notifications model where each entry is a notification. Every time a new entry is made into my SalesTask model , it invokes my signal handler which will create a new entry into my Notifications Model. I will then pass this model into my context and render it in my HTML.

```
    class Notifications(models.Model):
    notifications_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=100 ,default ='test')
    object_url = models.CharField(max_length=500, default ='test')
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)


def CreateTaskNotification(sender,**kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        notification = Notifications.objects.create(user = kwargs['instance'].salesExtra.username,
                                                    message = 'You have been assigned a new task',
                                                    object_url = kwargs['instance'].get_absolute_url(self)
                                                    )

post_save.connect(CreateTaskNotification,sender=SalesTask)
```

The issue with this is that my SalesTask Models :

```
class SalesTask(models.Model):
sales_status= (
    ('p1','Phase 1'),
    ('p2','Phase 2'),
    ('p3','Phase 3'),
    ('p4','Phase 4'),
)
sales_priority= (
    ('Urgent','Urgent'),
    ('Medium','Medium'),
    ('Low','Low'),
)
task_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
salesExtra= models.ManyToManyField('SalesExtra')
sales_project= models.ForeignKey('SalesProject',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.TextField(max_length=50 , default='Your Title' )
description = models.TextField(max_length=200 , default='Your Description' )
priority = models.TextField(max_length=10 , choices= sales_priority ,default='Low' )
date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
status = models.TextField(max_length=10, choices= sales_status ,default='p1')
due_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.task_id)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('sales-task')
```

has a many to many field with an extended model of User model (SalesExtra) . This is most probably why i am getting the error message :

```
'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'user'
```

This is my views for creating a new instance of a task:

```
class SalesTaskDetailView(CreateView):
model = SalesTaskingComments
template_name = 'rnd/task_details.html'
fields = ['comment']
exclude = ['comment_id']

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    pk = self.kwargs['pk']
    context = super(SalesTaskDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['sales_task'] = SalesTask.objects.filter(task_id = pk)
    context['comments'] = SalesTaskingComments.objects.filter(salesTask__task_id__contains= pk)
    return context

def form_valid(self, form):
    task = get_object_or_404(SalesTask, task_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
    user = get_object_or_404(SalesExtra, user=self.request.user)
    form.instance.salesTask = task
    form.instance.salesExtras = user
    return super(SalesTaskDetailView, self).form_valid(form)
```

My question therefore is : 
1. Is there a way to create a new entry for every SalesExtra object ? 
2. Is this the best method for creating a Notifications system? (i am using django 3.0 therefore many applications like django-notifications or django-activities-stream is not compatible.)

Answer (score 0):

If you create a [through table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) for the many to many relationship between `SalesTask` and `SalesExtra`, you can add the signal handler to this through table so that whenever a relationship is made between the 2 (a user has presumably been added) a notification will be made. If you save a `SalesTask` model form that has a multi select for the extras this will be triggered for each selection

```
class SalesTask(models.Model):
    salesExtra = models.ManyToManyField('SalesExtra', through='SalesTaskExtra')


class SalesExtra(models.Model):
    pass


class SalesTaskExtra(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(SalesTask, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    extra = models.ForeignKey(SalesExtra, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


def CreateTaskNotification(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        Notifications.objects.create(
            user=kwargs['instance'].extra.username,
            message='You have been assigned a new task',
            object_url=kwargs['instance'].task.get_absolute_url()
        )

post_save.connect(CreateTaskNotification, sender=SalesTaskExtra)
```

Comment: Hello , i tried this out and it worked for me , if you mind could you elaborate on the last part as i do not quite fully understand what u mean. Sorry im new to django!!

Comment: If the instance has just been created then `kwargs['instance'].salesExtra.all()` is surely returning an empty queryset?

Comment: Oh yes , i just tried to print out kwargs['instance'].salesExtra.all() , and it is indeed returning me an empty queryset , if you mind , why is this happening and is there a way for me to make it work? that would be of extremely great help to me

Comment: You could attach the signal handler to the `SalesExtra` model?

Comment: I am so sorry to ask this sir , but do you think it is possible to give me an example of how to do that as i do not know how i could attatch the handler to the SalesExtra model but still 'listen' for the creation of a new task instance

Comment: Do you have a view where you are saving the `SalesTask` and setting the many to many?

Comment: Yes i do , but i am mostly creating my instances through the admin page , i have updated the snippet above to include the view

Comment: Okay, I think it's better if you add the handler to the through table between the 2 models. Added some code

Comment: Hello sir , im so so sorry for asking so many questions , i have tried the method proposed. Im not too clear on the last part 'If you save a SalesTask model form that has a multi select for the extras this will be triggered for each selection' , could you please clarify on that ? As of now , for debugging purposes , im using the admin page to create new instances , but it seems that the 'through' parameter removes the option to choose the salesextras from the admin page , as such i need to manually create each relation in the salestaskextra table .